# Contact forms values goes into URL

Tags: php, html, wampserver, mail-server

So i´m currently working on a website where i want the customers to be able to mail directly to my email via a Contact Form. I am right now running all the files trough a wamp server 3 and right now I´m testing if the mail function works with Test Mail Server that listen to Port 25.

This is the PHP code for the form:

```
<?php

$myemail  = "test.xample@xample.com";

if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";

    /* Set e-mail recipient */

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $subject  = ($_POST['subject']);
    $email    = ($_POST['email']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    if ($name = "") 
    {
        show_error("You need to write your name...");
    }

    if ($email = "") 
    {
        show_error("You need to enter a email...");
    }

    if ($message = "") 
    {
        show_error("A message is required if you wish to have out help...");
    }
    /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
    $mail = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $yourname
    E-mail: $email

    Message:
    $Message

    End of message
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    /* Functions we used */
    function check_input($data, $problem='error')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the HTML part of the form:

```
<form class="mt-5 ml-5 mr-5" method="_POST" action="handler.php" id="reused_form">
        <p id="contactForm" class="h4 text-center mt-5"><strong>Kontakta oss</strong></p>

        <!-- input text(Name) -->
        <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix">*</i>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            <label for="name">Ditt namn</label>
        </div>

        <!-- input email -->
        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix">*</i>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control validate">
            <label for="email" data-error="Fel" data-success="Rätt">Din email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
            <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control">
            <label for="subject">Ämne</label>
        </div>

        <!-- input message -->
        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil prefix">*</i>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" maxlength="5000" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            <label for="textareaPrefix">Meddelande</label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
            <button class="btn danger-color" type="submit">Skicka</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When i press the Submit Button the only thing that happens is that this is added to the URL:

My inputs for this test:

- Name: asd
- email: asd@ad
- message: asd

`/handler.php?name=asd&email=asd%40ad&message=asd`

So it is just adding the values of the inputs in the URL...

What i need help with is how to solve this problem and be able to mail. I would be very pleased if someone could help with that.

Comment: Could you remove the underscore from your form method `_POST`? **EDIT** and here come the reputation farmers! Voted to close due to typo.

Comment: That will do it. Voting to close as just a simple typo.

Comment: I recommend you to use a PHP mail library like PHPMailer. It works or me.

Comment: @Amauri How does that solve their problem? The problem isn't with sending the email. It's with getting the data to the form in the manner they expect it.

Comment: Kind of a shame - someone goes to all the effort of providing an MCVE and creating quite a reasonable question (rather than d/v -> close -> move on) ... all for the sake of one little `_` :|

Comment: @JohnConde The PHPMailer connects to a remote SMTP server and sends the email (like Gmail, hotmail, or your site host smtp server), so, you just need to configure it. Here you can find A LOT OF examples: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples fave fun :)

Comment: @JohnConde usually when you try to send an email from a local server (like WAMP) it probably not work.

Comment: @Amauri But that's not what their problem is. The problem is they are getting their form values sent via GET instead of POST like they were expecting. It has nothing to do with sending their emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Such a easy fix haha :)

Comment: Why u guys think it's off topic??

Comment: Read the details of the reason: a typo (underscore prefixed to HTTP verb) is a sub-type of off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo are using `method=_POST` which is not correct method so in default, the form uses `GET method` to send the data.

Please try using `method=POST` instead of `method=_POST` and it will work perfectly.

```
<form method="POST">
   .........
</form>
```

Comment: When the answer is "you have an unneeded underscore", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked :)

Comment: please mark as accepted answer if it worked for you :)